# Looking for someone to help me write a very simple javascript with a countup timer that changes speed

Tags: javascript, timer

I can't get this to work.  I've been searching online for examples that I could modify, but I am stuck.  I don't plan on mastering javascript, so if anyone can provide a simple answer I would appreciate it.

Trying to make this counter count up, and clicking the button will make it slow down the speed at which it counts up...

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>COUNTUP TOOL</h2>

<button onclick="slow_function()">slow/resume</button>

<label id="seconds">0</label>

<script>
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
var interval_between_ticks = 1000;
setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);

function setTime() {
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}

function  slow_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 10000;
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `setInterval` function uses the value that was provided at its instantiation.  In order to change the interval, you will have to clear the previous interval and set a new one with the new time, something like:

```js
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
var interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Assign the interval to a variable to keep track of it
var interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);

function setTime() {
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}

function  slow_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 10000;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>COUNTUP TOOL</h2>

<button onclick="slow_function()">slow/resume</button>

<label id="seconds">0</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried cutting & pasting what you gave me but I have the same result...

Comment: What browser are you testing in?  When you click Run code snippet on my snippet, does it work on your side?  I only added three lines in. I would recommend just copying those three lines into your code exactly where I have them in mine.  You will have to replace your setInterval line with my first setInterval line